# Using flex to center and stretch background

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I horizontally and vertically center this smiley on top of the image while also stretching it to 50% of the size of its container?

I.e. like:

[image]

```css
.test {
    display: flex;
}
.test .smile {
    background-image: url(https://rawgit.com/anonymous/9f37047667b06af42c3d/raw/65a00b0f38b05bb6c96fa827993dbae31fe391b3/test.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <a>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
        <span class="smile"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only been able to get flexbox to work when the container has a height set. [Here's a fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/gfezv40o/). Since your aligned image is set as a background image, there's no easy way to get the width and height set. If it was an image, you'd easily be able to do a width of 50% and the height would take care of itself.

```
.test {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400) no-repeat;
}
.test .smile {
    background-image: url(https://rawgit.com/anonymous/9f37047667b06af42c3d/raw/65a00b0f38b05bb6c96fa827993dbae31fe391b3/test.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You only need to set the height of the .smile class if you're using the svg. [Here's an example with an image centered](http://jsfiddle.net/gfezv40o/2/).